# Menu links won't appear

Tags: navigation

I generated 2 entities and addtyed a new Form with the overview of them. But when I try to add links, they won't appear.  I follow the guide but wont work. Form and Entities work. The routings are generated with drupal generate:entity

links.tasks.yml:

```
# Timeslot routing definition
timeslot.settings_tab:
  route_name: timeslot.settings
  title: 'Settings'
  base_route: timeslot.settings

entity.timeslot.canonical:
  route_name: entity.timeslot.canonical
  base_route: entity.timeslot.canonical
  title: 'View'

entity.timeslot.edit_form:
  route_name: entity.timeslot.edit_form
  base_route: entity.timeslot.canonical
  title: 'Edit'

entity.timeslot.version_history:
  route_name: entity.timeslot.version_history
  base_route: entity.timeslot.canonical
  title: 'Revisions'

entity.timeslot.delete_form:
  route_name:  entity.timeslot.delete_form
  base_route:  entity.timeslot.canonical
  title: Delete
  weight: 10

# Issue timeslot routing definition
issue_timeslot.settings_tab:
  route_name: issue_timeslot.settings
  title: 'Settings'
  base_route: issue_timeslot.settings

entity.issue_timeslot.canonical:
  route_name: entity.issue_timeslot.canonical
  base_route: entity.issue_timeslot.canonical
  title: 'View'

entity.issue_timeslot.edit_form:
  route_name: entity.issue_timeslot.edit_form
  base_route: entity.issue_timeslot.canonical
  title: 'Edit'

entity.issue_timeslot.version_history:
  route_name: entity.issue_timeslot.version_history
  base_route: entity.issue_timeslot.canonical
  title: 'Revisions'

entity.issue_timeslot.delete_form:
  route_name:  entity.issue_timeslot.delete_form
  base_route:  entity.issue_timeslot.canonical
  title: Delete
  weight: 10
```

links.menu.yml

```
# Timeslot menu items definition
entity.timeslot.collection:
  title: 'Timeslot list'
  route_name: entity.timeslot.collection
  description: 'List Timeslot entities'
  parent: system.admin_structure
  weight: 100

timeslot.admin.structure.settings:
  title: 'Timeslot settings'
  description: 'Configure Timeslot entities'
  route_name: timeslot.settings
  parent: system.admin_structure

# Issue timeslot menu items definition
entity.issue_timeslot.collection:
  title: 'Issue timeslot list'
  route_name: entity.issue_timeslot.collection
  description: 'List Issue timeslot entities'
  parent: system.admin_structure
  weight: 100

issue_timeslot.admin.structure.settings:
  title: 'Issue timeslot settings'
  description: 'Configure Issue timeslot entities'
  route_name: issue_timeslot.settings
  parent: system.admin_structure

trivali_crm_supportcontract.timeslots:
  title: 'Timeslots'
  route_name:
  weight: 100
  menu_name: main
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.

Please never paste images of your IDE showing code excerpts, but paste in the relevant parts in text form here. This allows search engines to better index your question for others that may search with similar issues.

Apart from this, I have a hard time figuring out which links don't show up. The entity links or the ones of your custom controller? The links/routes of your images seem to be unrelated? Please add some more details in order to receive a good answer.

Comment: Have you prefixed those file names with the module name?